# Binning task: I have a list of frequencies which I need to put in bins, facing errors

Tags: python, list, fft, binning

I have `df['freq']`, this is a list of numbers stored as `['0.0','0.3','0.9]`.
My task is to classify them into 30 bins(from `0.0, 0.1,0.2...... till 3.`0)

1. I have used the ravel function to flatten it
2. Made a new_list for storing these strings as float

   ```
    def binning_function(col,cut_points,labels=None):
    minval = 0.0
    maxval = 3.0
    break_points = [minval] + cut_points + [maxval]
    print(break_points)
    if not labels:
        labels = range(len(cut_points) + 1)

    colbin = pd.cut(col,bins=break_points, labels=labels,include_lowest = True ) 

    return colbin
   ```

Please refer to this code snippet:
[image: Please refer to this code snippet]

The error is

> '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'list'

Comment: Where is the place you are using `<`? I don't see it in the picture. Also, actual code is better than a image, for future reference.

Comment: Please avoid screenshot, copy/paste your code instead.

Comment: pd.cut() expects a 1d array-like, `new_list` is not 1d which could cause the issue, although hard to tell without proper example. See: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending the list x_elem instead of each value. As a result, the program is comparing a list and a number which is not allowed. So append each value by modifying the for loop.

```
for x_elem in range(len(flat)):
    x_elem = df_ft['freq'].iloc[_].strip("[]").split(", ")
    x_elem = list2float(x_elem)
    for elem in x_elem:
        new_list.append(elem)
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks this worked, facing another issue that "Bin labels must be one fewer than the number of bin edges", resolving this now.

Comment: Yes! Thanks, it worked! I have accepted this answer already!